# Exporting emails from outlook programmatically with vba

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm using this script to export email from outlook.  My question is how do I export the body of the email without the html formatting?

```
Sub SaveItemsToExcel()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandlerExit

   Dim oNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
   Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

   Dim objFS As Scripting.FileSystemObject
   Dim objOutputFile As Scripting.TextStream

   Set objFS = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
   Set objOutputFile = objFS.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Export.csv", ForWriting, True)
   Set oNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set oFolder = oNameSpace.PickFolder

   If oFolder Is Nothing Then
      GoTo ErrorHandlerExit
   End If

    If oFolder.DefaultItemType <> olMailItem Then
      MsgBox "Folder does not contain mail messages"
      GoTo ErrorHandlerExit
    End If

    objOutputFile.WriteLine "From,Subject,Recived, Body"

    ProcessFolderItems oFolder, objOutputFile

    objOutputFile.Close

    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oNameSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutputFile = Nothing
    Set objFS = Nothing

ErrorHandlerExit:
   Exit Sub


End Sub

Sub ProcessFolderItems(oParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, ByRef objOutputFile As Scripting.TextStream)
    Dim oCount As Integer
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    oCount = oParentFolder.Items.Count

    For Each oMail In oParentFolder.Items
        If oMail.Class = olMail Then

        objOutputFile.WriteLine oMail.SenderEmailAddress & "," & Replace(oMail.Subject, ",", "") & "," & oMail.ReceivedTime

        End If
    Next oMail

    Set oMail = Nothing
    If (oParentFolder.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParentFolder.Folders
                ProcessFolderItems oFolder, objOutputFile
            Next
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `BodyFormat` to `olFormatPlain` before reading `Body` property.